# Which Cloud Provider Product supports Event Sourcing with Event Subscription?

Tags: cloud, event-sourcing

For a new project, I want to use Event Sourcing and CQRS. So, I want to store all changes to application state as a **sequence** of events. Further any of my services should be able to subscribe to the event stream emitted by other services.

These are my requirements:

1. Only as-a-service products, no installation of Kafka or other software.
2. Preserve the order of events from a consumer. * (see example below)
3. Support for multiple event producers and multiple event consumers. * (see example below)
4. New events must be pushed to consumers that subscribe for a topic.
5. Storage of events is only necessary till all consumers have processed the event because consumers can persist and aggregate events.

These requirements are nice-to-have:

6. Should scale linearly.
7. Should scale automatically.
8. The delivery time should be < 100 ms 99% of the time if the producer and consumer are in the same region.
9. Should store event data as binary without requiring to convert to/from Base64.
10. Should be pay-as-you-go with initial costs during development below 20 EUR per month.

* Example for event order with multiple producers and consumers:
An example with two producers and two consumers. The first producer publishes events A, B, C the second publishes events 1, 2, 3. Then the first and second consumer may both get A, B, C, 1, 2, 3 or A, 1, 2, B, C, 3 but not A, C, B, 1, 2, 3. Further all consumers need to get the exact same order of all events.

I found that Amazon Kinesis Data Streams would meet my requirements but I am surprised that I could not find a comparable solution from Google Cloud or Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Serialized (https://serialized.io) provides a SaaS specifically for building Event Sourcing and CQRS solutions. It's fully managed and delivered via APIs, currently hosted on AWS and available via AWS marketplace.

Full disclosure: I'm the CEO of Serialized.

Hope this helps.